# Multifunction printer / scanner that can *easily* be accessed over the network

Tags: networking, printer, scanner

A few more details:

- Network scanner is the most important function; the less software it requires to play with OSX the better (looking at you, HP)
- Decent-ish printer is a nice to have; ideally with a 2nd paper tray (to feed in other types of paper as necessary
- Scanner needs to have a paper feeder function; flatbed is nice to have, but need to be able to load a stack of documents and have them feed through
- Reasonable price - ideally somewhere between $150-$500

Have looked through Canon and HPs offerings and nothing jumps out - the biggest variable being if network scanning requires software on each machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Brother MFC-6890CDW, and it works with the default (new) OSX scanner software (Image Capture).  You don't need to install anything.  It works wireless out of the box, too.  There's a review at MacWorld you can google.  It's about $300.

I literally threw my HP gear into the trash because I was so tired of HP clearly not knowing how to write software.  Their consumables are expensive too.  I've switched to Brother across the board, better software and (much) cheaper consumables.

Comment: Thanks Peter - will check out that model.  HP is ridiculous with the amount of bloated software they require you to install for their products, that's why I'm trying to avoid them.

Will take a closer look at that Brother model.  Cheers!

Comment: Went with the Brother MFC-7840W (http://www.brother-usa.com/mfc/modeldetail.aspx?PRODUCTID=MFC7840W&tab=spec) in the end. Played around with the SCAN TO FTP feature but wasn't able to get it to connect to a local or remote FTP server.

Fortunately the printer supports Apple's Bonjour protocol & appeared on the network - MAGICALLY, OSX's Image Capture app detected it as a network scanner and is able to scan remotely, which is perfect.

There is a severe lack of support/documentation for SCAN TO FTP (or email!) feature, which isn't a surprise. Glad this is working as required. Thanks!

Comment: Best part also was getting the desired functionality WITHOUT INSTALLING ANY SOFTWARE (thanks to the web management interface, although bare bones...)

Answer (score 1):

We use a [Ricoh Aficio SP 3200SF](http://www.ricoh-usa.com/products/product_features.asp?pCategoryId=2&pCatName=Multifunction+B+%26+W&tsn=Ricoh-USA&pSubCategoryId=2&pSubCatName=23-45%20ppm&pProductId=884&pProductName=Aficio%20SP%203200SF).  It scans to USB, FTP, SMB, or to the Ricoh software.  It only does TIFF or PDF, though.  Also, the document feeder doesn't hold to many sheets (maybe 10-15).

Comment: Thanks very much - will check into that model, didn't even consider Ricoh

Answer (score 0):

I use the HP office jet 7310xi, got at costco for $200 or so, im sure there is a newer version, but works great with mac and windows and does all the stuff you want above. You have to order the 2nd tray, but you can get one. The current rev is probably newer, but the office jet 73xx series are nice.

Comment: Thanks Joelio - I'm wary of HP because it often requires a lot of software to be installed.  Do you have to install their software to enable network scanning?